# Explain the output of the stack implemented using linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am creating a stack with a linked list. I have coded the push and display stack portion but it is just producing the last entered data as output when I am trying to display the stack content. Why is this happening?

```
struct LinkedStack {
    int data;
    struct LinkedStack* next;
};

struct LinkedStack *first = NULL;
struct LinkedStack *previous = NULL;
struct LinkedStack *current = NULL;

int main(void) {
    int data = 0, choice = 0;
    if(current == NULL) {
         printf("\nNo Memory Allocated");
    }
    while(1) {
        printf("\n1. Push Data");
        printf("\n2. Pop Data");
        printf("\n3. Display The Stack");
        printf("\n4. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice::\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedStack));
                printf("Enter the data:: ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                push(&current, data);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\n\n Stack Contents::");
                displayStack(current);
                break;
           case 4:
                exit(1);
           default:
                printf("\nWrong Choice.Enter Again");

        }
    }

}

void push(struct LinkedStack **s, int usrdata) {
    if(first == NULL) {
        first = *s;
    }  
    if(previous != NULL) {
          previous->next = *s;
    } 

    (*s)->data = usrdata;;
    (*s)->next = NULL;
    previous = *s;
}

void displayStack(struct LinkedStack *s) {
    struct LinkedStack *temp = (struct LinkedStack *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedStack));
    if(temp == NULL) {
        printf("No Memory Allocated");
    }
    temp = s;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("\n %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: read the question once more. I have written everything over there. It couldn't have been more specific than this.

Comment: In case 3, displayStack(first) to display the entire list.  If you displayStack(current), it will only display the last item.  Also, you don't need to malloc in displayStack.

Comment: at displayStack : no need `malloc`.

Comment: remove `(struct node *)`. put prototype `push` and `displayStack`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing the data correctly, then try

```
  case 3:
         printf("\n\n Stack Contents::");
         displayStack(first);
         break;
```

instead of

```
     case 3:
         printf("\n\n Stack Contents::");
         displayStack(current);
         break;
```

The displayStack() function needs a reference to the front of your linked list.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @user1370217- I have tried that according to your suggestion,but now it is just displaying the first two data in the stack and ignoring the rest. Could you please go through the push() and confirm whether its okay or not. If its okay then why is the rest of the data are not getting displayed?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to start by removing those global variables.  Try to think of the stack as a single variable of type `LinkedStack *`.

Then implement `push` and `pop` in terms of that.  No global variables: the caller of those functions passes in a pointer to that variable, i.e. the functions should have signatures:

```
void push(LinkedStack **stack, int data);
int pop(LinkedStack **stack);
```

This is what you're doing already, so my guess is you have at least some of the right ideas. ;)

Questions to ask yourself:

- what does an empty stack look like?
- what happens if I `push` to an empty stack?  (Do not worry about popping from an empty stack at this stage; worry about that when everything else is working.)
- how does memory for a LinkedStack node get freed when something is popped?
- how is the caller's `LinkedStack *` variable updated by `push` and `pop` ?